# How to use override parameters of a fixture in Pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

Let's say I have a parameterized fixture like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2, 800]):
def resource(request):
    return Resource(capacity=request.param)
```

When I use the fixture as parameter in a test function, Pytest runs the test with all three versions:

```
def test_resource(resource):  # Runs for capacities 1, 2, and 800.
    assert resource.is_okay()
```

However, for some tests I want to change the parameters for which the fixture gets built:

```
def test_worker(resource, worker):  # Please run this for capacities 1 and 5.
    worker.use(resource)
    assert worker.is_okay()
```

How can I specify to only receive certain versions of the specified fixture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use different set of parameters for different tests then `pytest.mark.parametrize` is helpful.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("resource", [1, 2, 800], indirect=True)
def test_resource(resource):
    assert resource.is_okay()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("resource", [1, 5], indirect=True)
def test_resource_other(resource):
    assert resource.is_okay()
```

Comment: The `indirect=True` bit seems to be one of the poorly-documented gems of pytest! Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you can configure it *"to only receive certain versions"*, but you can explicitly ignore some of them:

```
def test_worker(resource, worker):
    if resource.capacity == 800:
        pytest.skip("reason why that value won't work")
    worker.use(resource)
    assert worker.is_okay()
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to request the fixture for *new* parameters, though?

Comment: @danijar what do you mean? If you think this functionality should be added to the package check its website to see where the maintainers want these kind of suggestions. I'd suggest you come up with a more compelling and less abstract use case, though.

Comment: In the example above, the fixture is defined for the parameters 1, 2, and 800. But in some cases, I want to use the fixture with other parameters. I can ignore parameters using `pytest.skip()` as you showed (I assume that there should be a `return` after that line), but I cannot add new parameters, such as 5.

Comment: @danijar in that case you add it to the fixture and use the same method to skip it where you don't want it. Again, a more concrete example might be helpful; why are you parameterizing in this way? Have you read e.g. http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html?